# Disassembly in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to check the generated assembly code of the compiler optimized parts (release) of my C++ code in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.
There are articles on the web about a Disassembly window, but I can't access it.

Comment: You must run debug and hit breakpoint. Then you can view it in Debug->Windows->Disassembly

Comment: You can generate assembly output (listing), or use another software for full-executable disassembly (like OllyDbg for debugging&disassembly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the property page of the cpp file containing the function you desire inspect the disassembly, go to the "Output files" category and you can enable an assembly dump to a provided filename.

Answer (score 6):

The disassembly window is available during debugging of applications through the menu

- Debug -> Window -> Disassembly

It is possible that the Visual Studio profile you chose excluded this option.  If so then you can just invoke the following command from the Command Window while debugging and it will show the window

- View -> Other Windows -> Command Window
- Type: Debug.Disassembly

Comment: Then:

* Break execution (Ctrl-F5 or the pause button)

* Enter the name of the function you want to disassemble in the **Address** field on the Disassembly window

(This is what it took for me to see the assembly code on AtmelStudio, based on MS Visual Studio.)

Comment: Note that "Enable address-level debugging" must be checked under Tools > Options > Debugging > General in order for the Disassembly window to be available.